# Failed to execute user defined function in Apache Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following dataframe:

```
+---------------+-----------+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------+-----+
|   time_stamp_0|sender_ip_1|receiver_ip_2|s_port_3|r_port_4|acknum_5|winnum_6| len_7|count|
+---------------+-----------+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------+-----+
|06:36:16.293711|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58| 65161|  130|
|06:36:16.293729|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58| 65913|  130|
|06:36:16.293743|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|131073|  130|
|06:36:16.293765|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|196233|  130|
|06:36:16.293783|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|196985|  130|
|06:36:16.293798|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|262145|  130|
|06:36:16.293820|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|327305|  130|
|06:36:16.293837|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|328057|  130|
|06:36:16.293851|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|393217|  130|
|06:36:16.293873|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|458377|  130|
|06:36:16.293890|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|459129|  130|
|06:36:16.293904|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|524289|  130|
|06:36:16.293926|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|589449|  130|
|06:36:16.293942|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|590201|  130|
|06:36:16.293956|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|655361|  130|
|06:36:16.293977|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|720521|  130|
|06:36:16.293994|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|721273|  130|
|06:36:16.294007|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|786433|  130|
|06:36:16.294028|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|851593|  130|
|06:36:16.294045|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|   55518|    5001|       0|      58|852345|  130|
+---------------+-----------+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

I have to add features and label to my `dataframe` to predict the count value. However as I ran the code I will see the below error:

```
Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$15: (int, int, string, string, int, int, int, int, int) => vector)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
```

I also `cast(IntegerType)` all my features but again the error occurs. Here is my code:

```
val Frist_Dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Row_Dstream_Train, customSchema)

       val toVec9 = udf[Vector, Int, Int, String, String, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int] { (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) =>
              val e3 = c match {
                case "10.0.0.1" => 1
                case "10.0.0.2" => 2
                case "10.0.0.3" => 3
              }

              val e4 = d match {
                case "10.0.0.1" => 1
                case "10.0.0.2" => 2
                case "10.0.0.3" => 3
              }
              Vectors.dense(a, b, e3, e4, e, f, g, h, i)
            }

            val final_df = Dataframe.withColumn(
              "features",
              toVec9(
                // casting into Timestamp to parse the string, and then into Int
                $"time_stamp_0".cast(TimestampType).cast(IntegerType),
                $"count".cast(IntegerType),
                $"sender_ip_1",
                $"receiver_ip_2",
                $"s_port_3".cast(IntegerType),
                $"r_port_4".cast(IntegerType),
                $"acknum_5".cast(IntegerType),
                $"winnum_6".cast(IntegerType),
                $"len_7".cast(IntegerType)
              )
            ).withColumn("label", (Dataframe("count"))).select("features", "label")
```

final_df.show()

```
val trainingTest = final_df.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2))
val TrainingDF = trainingTest(0).toDF()
val TestingDF=trainingTest(1).toDF()
TrainingDF.show()
TestingDF.show()
```

My dependencies also are:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "co.theasi" %% "plotly" % "0.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.1"
)
```

The funnest point is that if I change all my `cast(IntegerType)` to `cast(TimestampType).cast(IntegerType)` in the last part of my code, the error disappear and the output will be something like this:

```
+--------+-----+
|features|label|
+--------+-----+
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
|    null|  130|
+--------+-----+
```

**UPDATE**: After applying @Ramesh Maharjan solution the result of my dataframe works well but, whenever I try to splitting my final_df dataframe into training and testing the result is something like below and I still have the same problem of having null rows.

```
+--------------------+-----+
|            features|label|
+--------------------+-----+
|                null|  130|
|                null|  130|
|                null|  130|
|                null|  130|
|                null|  130|
|                null|  130|
|                null|  130|
|                null|  130|
|[1.497587776E9,13...|  130|
|[1.497587776E9,13...|  130|
|[1.497587776E9,13...|  130|
|[1.497587776E9,13...|  130|
|[1.497587776E9,13...|  130|
|[1.497587776E9,13...|  130|
|[1.497587776E9,13...|  130|
|[1.497587776E9,13...|  130|
|[1.497587776E9,13...|  130|
|[1.497587776E9,13...|  130|
|[1.497587776E9,13...|  130|
|[1.497587776E9,13...|  130|
+--------------------+-----+
```

Can you help me?

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do with the udf? Because you dont write udf as above in scala ?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala: thanks for your answer, I think you are right it needs more explanation. This question is according to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563672/extract-specific-columns-form-a-text-file-to-make-a-dataframe-in-scala

Comment: you already got the answer didn't you ?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala: I need vector of feature to predict the "count" value and all the member of vectore should be integer so, I use  udf, since some of my variables are in string and I need to convert them into integer in some way. The Raw data of my code is in my pervious question also.

Comment: @ShankarKoirala: Of course not, it was on how to extracting the data. Ok I will add all my code here.

Comment: @ShankarKoirala: I have updated the question

Comment: so do you wanna change    $"sender_ip_1" and $"receiver_ip_2"column value to integer

Comment: @ShankarKoirala: yes I want.

Comment: @ShankarKoirala: The problem is that error! :( There is problem in casting part in the last part of my code. Because, before that I added s_port_3, r_port_4, acknum_5, winnum_6 and len_7, everything works fine! I don't know the correct way of casting there!

Comment: @Queen how did you generate the count column in your dataframe?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't see `count column` being generated in your question code. Apart from `count` column @Shankar's answer should get you the result you want.

Following error was due to wrong definition of `udf` function which @Shankar had it corrected in his answer.

```
Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$15: (int, int, string, string, int, int, int, int, int) => vector)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
```

Following error is due to `version` mismatch of `spark-mllib library` with `spark-core library` and `spark-sql library`. They all should be of same version.

```
error: Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$15: (int, int, string, string, int, int, int, int, int) => vector) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$Gen‌​eratedIterator.proce‌​ssNext(Unknown Source)
```

I hope the explanation is clear and hope to see your problem get solved soon.

**Edited**

You haven't still changed the `udf` function as @Shankar had suggested. Add `.trim` too as I can see some spaces

```
val toVec9 = udf ((a: Int, b: Int, c: String, d: String, e: Int, f: Int, g: Int, h: Int, i: Int) =>
  {
  val e3 = c.trim match {
    case "10.0.0.1" => 1
    case "10.0.0.2" => 2
    case "10.0.0.3" => 3
  }
  val e4 = d.trim match {
    case "10.0.0.1" => 1
    case "10.0.0.2" => 2
    case "10.0.0.3" => 3
  }
  Vectors.dense(a, b, e3, e4, e, f, g, h, i)
})
```

And looking at your dependencies, you are using `%%` which tells `sbt` to download the `dependencies` packaged with `scala` version in your system. That should be fine but since you are still getting errors, I would like to change the `dependencies` as

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "co.theasi" %% "plotly" % "0.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "2.1.1"

)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, non of the reasons that you mentioned were not the cause of that error. I have updated the question. I have the same version of spark-core library and spark-sql library. Also the count exist in my code. I just added it to see that it exist.

Comment: @Queen  thanks for updating the question with count column. I have updated my answer. If you still face issues do let me know. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works fine and I will accept this answer as a correct answer. But as a final question I have the last same error when I split the final_df into training and testing part. Could please check why the training and testing has null again. I have updated the question again.

Comment: That should be another question. But I will help you. Answer every question I ask. the codes in the question is as in your system? the sequential order?

Comment: @Thanks a lot for your kindness. Yes the sequential is the same as my code in my system. :)

Comment: can you provide me some more sample input data as i am not getting nulls with those two input lines?

Comment: I got it from above :)

Comment: @I have uploaded the full file. Please use them. Thanks a lot.

Comment: sure, in the meantime would your change the dependencies to 2.0.2 instead of 2.1.1 of spark-core, spark-sql and spark-mllib?

Comment: I tried with spark dependent version of 2.0.2 on whole dataset and i didn't get any nulls. And the label column had 147 instead of 130.

Comment: Is there any way to drop the null values in the dataframe?

Comment: I found out the issue . how can i copy paste my code like you did?

Comment: first change the line from `StructField("len_7", StringType, true)))` and change it to `StructField("len_7", IntegerType, true)))`

Comment: And change `val eighth = Try(len7.substring(len7.lastIndexOf(":")+1, len7.length)) getOrElse "0"` copy paste the following to the above `val eighth = Try(len7.substring(len7.lastIndexOf(":")+1, len7.length).toInt) getOrElse 0`

Comment: Oh realy, Thanks a lot, You can upload it easily here, then send me the link: https://sendit.gl/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Italy&utm_term=free%20upload%20P&utm_content=Keyword%20T&gclid=Cj0KEQjwg47KBRDk7LSu4LTD8eEBEiQAO4O6ryHR7BZRQG0vL2A3dXBwZ6hebxWNte7JHqIWV_RBrvYaAubB8P8HAQ

Comment: great to hear that @Queen do I still need to send you the file? As I am struggling here finding your email id. :) hehe

Comment: thanks for accepting :) and an upvote when you have enough reputation ;) thanks

Comment: Surly I will do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how you create an udf

```
val toVec9 = udf ((a: Int, b: Int, c: String, d: String, e: Int, f: Int, g: Int, h: Int, i: Int) =>
{
  val e3 = c match {
    case "10.0.0.1" => 1
    case "10.0.0.2" => 2
    case "10.0.0.3" => 3
  }

  val e4 = d match {
    case "10.0.0.1" => 1
    case "10.0.0.2" => 2
    case "10.0.0.3" => 3
  }
  Vectors.dense(a, b, e3, e4, e, f, g, h, i)

})
```

And use it as

```
val final_df = Dataframe.withColumn(
              "features",
              toVec9(
                // casting into Timestamp to parse the string, and then into Int
                $"time_stamp_0".cast(TimestampType).cast(IntegerType),
                $"count".cast(IntegerType),
                $"sender_ip_1",
                $"receiver_ip_2",
                $"s_port_3".cast(IntegerType),
                $"r_port_4".cast(IntegerType),
                $"acknum_5".cast(IntegerType),
                $"winnum_6".cast(IntegerType),
                $"len_7".cast(IntegerType)
              )
            ).withColumn("label", (Dataframe("count"))).select("features", "label")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, again the same error:
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$15: (int, int, string, string, int, int, int, int, int) => vector)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)

Comment: Do you have any idea about the casting part?