# Explode sparse features vector into separate columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

In my spark DataFrame I have a column which includes the output of a `CountVectoriser` transformation - it is in sparse vector format. What I am trying to do is to 'explode' this column again into a dense vector and then it's component rows (so that it can be used for scoring by an external model).

I know there are 40 features in the column, hence Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110038/spark-scala-how-to-convert-dataframevector-to-dataframef1double-fn-d) example, I have tried:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector

// convert sparse vector to a dense vector, and then to array<double> 
val vecToSeq = udf((v: Vector) => v.toArray)

// Prepare a list of columns to create
val exprs = (0 until 39).map(i => $"_tmp".getItem(i).alias(s"exploded_col$i"))
testDF.select(vecToSeq($"features").alias("_tmp")).select(exprs:_*)
```

However, I get the weird error (see full error below):

`data type mismatch: argument 1 requires vector type, however, 'features' is of vector type.;`

Now it appears that maybe the CountVectoriser created a vector of type 'ml.linalg.Vector,' so I have alternatively tried importing:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Vector, DenseVector, SparseVector}
```

And then I get an error Caused by:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Row
```

I have also tried converting the ml vector by altering the UDF to:

```
val vecToSeq = udf((v: Vector) =>  org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors.fromML(v.toDense).toArray )
```

And get a similar `cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Row` error. Can anyone tell me why this is not working? Is there an easier way to explode a sparse vector in a DataFrame into sperate columns? I've spent hours on this and cannot figure it out.

EDIT: The schema shows the feature column just as a vector:

```
  |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```

Full error trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'UDF(features)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires vector type, however, 'features' is of vector type.;;
Project [UDF(features#325) AS _tmp#463]
. . . 
org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@47eae91d

        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpression$1(QueryPlan.scala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:293)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$6.apply(QueryPlan.scala:298)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.mapExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:298)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withPlan(Dataset.scala:2872)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Dataset.scala:1153)
        at uk.nominet.renewals.prediction_test$.prediction_test(prediction_test.scala:292)
        at
```

Comment: Could you show schema? And what is `categorisation_split_vec`?

Comment: added the schema.  `categorisation_split_vec` is the actual name of the `features` column, I renamed it for simplicity (though not everywhere - now fixed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with your import statements. As you noticed, `CountVectorizer` will use the `ml` package vectors, therefore, all vector imports should also use this package. Make sure you do not have any imports using the older `mllib`. This include:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector
```

There are some methods only present in the `mllib` package, so in the case you actually need to use this type of vectors, you can rename them (since the name is the same as the `ml` vectors otherwise). For example:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector => mllibVector}
```

After fixing all imports, your code should run. Test:

```
val df = Seq((1L, Seq("word1", "word2", "word3")), (2L, Seq("word2", "word4"))).toDF("id", "words")
val countVec = new CountVectorizer().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("features")
val testDF = countVec.fit(df).transform(df)
```

Will give a testing dataframe as follows:

```
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
| id|               words|            features|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1|[word1, word2, wo...|(4,[0,2,3],[1.0,1...|
|  2|      [word2, word4]| (4,[0,1],[1.0,1.0])|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Now to give each index it's own column:

```
val vecToSeq = udf((v: Vector) => v.toArray)

val exprs = (0 until 4).map(i => $"features".getItem(i).alias(s"exploded_col$i"))
val df2 = testDF.withColumn("features", vecToSeq($"features")).select(exprs:_*)
```

Resulting dataFfame:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|exploded_col0|exploded_col1|exploded_col2|exploded_col3|
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|          1.0|          0.0|          1.0|          1.0|
|          1.0|          1.0|          0.0|          0.0|
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This SHOULD work, it's pretty much what I have been trying. When I run it on the testDF it works great, but on my real DF, which has an identical sparseVector column created by CountVectoriser, I still get errors (`Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$1: (vector) => array<double>)` . . . `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Row`). The `df.struct("features")` of both DFs are identical (`StructField(features,org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7,true)`). I have no idea why?

Comment: Also: all my imports are fine - the error appears to come from the initial `vecToSeq` function and a data format mismatch.

Comment: @renegademonkey: How does the real dataframe look like? Can you add it to the question?

Comment: It's too large (a mixture of 40 features with a combination of Integers, Timestamps, Doubles, Strings, Arrays), but this shouldn't be relevant? The same error occurs if I filter the whole DF down to just the `features` column and try to run `vecToSeq` on that.

Comment: @renegademonkey: A sample of the `features` column would be sufficient then. If you take say 5 rows of that column and run the `vecToSeq`, does it still give the error?

Comment: It's in the expected sparseVector format:  format 
` (40,[4],[1.0]) | (40,[1],[1.0]) | (40,[5],[1.0]) | (40,[0],[1.0]) `

Comment: @renegademonkey: Can you if it works when running on part of the data, you can use `.take(x)` to try.

Comment: @renegademonkey: Check so the versions of all spark libraries are correct and the same, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44570303/failed-to-execute-user-defined-function-in-apache-spark-using-scala

Comment: OMG, by looking into my `pom.xml` file to check the spark versions (which all match) I realised that I had been running this object without re-packaging the whole app. This works in most instances, but obviously not with some UDFs. [facepalm]. Now everything works as it should! Thank you for persevering with me.

Comment: @renegademonkey: Glad you could solve it in the end :)

Answer (score 4):

When working such cases, I often decompose step by step to know where the issue is coming from.

First, let's setup a dataframe :

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
val df=sc.parallelize(Seq((1L, Seq("word1", "word2")))).toDF("id", "words")
val countModel = new CountVectorizer().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("feature").fit(df)
val testDF = countModel.transform(df)
testDF.show

+---+--------------+-------------------+
| id|         words|            feature|
+---+--------------+-------------------+
|  1|[word1, word2]|(2,[0,1],[1.0,1.0])|
+---+--------------+-------------------+
```

Now, what I would like is to select, say the first column of feature, that is to say, extract the first coordinate of the `feature` vector.

That could be written : `v(0)`.
Now I want my dataframe to have a column that holds `v(0)` where `v` is the `feature` column's content. I may use a User Defined Function for that :

```
val firstColumnExtractor = udf((v: Vector) => v(0))
```

And I try to add this column to my `testDF`

```
testDF.withColumn("feature_0", firstColumnExtractor($"feature")).show
+---+--------------+-------------------+---------+                              
| id|         words|            feature|feature_0|
+---+--------------+-------------------+---------+
|  1|[word1, word2]|(2,[0,1],[1.0,1.0])|      1.0|
+---+--------------+-------------------+---------+
```

Note that I could just as well do it this way (this is just a matter of style, as far as I can tell):

```
testDF.select(firstColumnExtractor($"feature").as("feature_0")).show
```

This works, but that is a lot of work to repeat. Let's automate.
First, I can generalize the extracting function to work at any index. Let's create a higher order function (a function that creates functions)

```
def columnExtractor(idx: Int) = udf((v: Vector) => v(idx))
```

Now, I can rewrite the previous example :

```
testDF.withColumn("feature_0", columnExtractor(0)($"feature")).show
```

OK, so now I could do it this way :

```
testDF.withColumn("feature_0", columnExtractor(0)($"feature"))
      .withColumn("feature_1", columnExtractor(1)($"feature"))
```

That works for 1, but what about 39 dimensions ? Well, let's automate some more. The above really is a `foldLeft` operation on each dimension :

```
(0 to 39).foldLeft(testDF)((df, idx) => df.withColumn("feature_"+idx, columnExtractor(idx)($"feature")))
```

Which is just another way of writing your function with multiple selects

```
val featureCols = (0 to 1).map(idx => columnExtractor(idx)($"feature").as("feature_"+idx))
testDF.select((col("*") +: featureCols):_*).show
+---+--------------+-------------------+---------+---------+
| id|         words|            feature|feature_0|feature_1|
+---+--------------+-------------------+---------+---------+
|  1|[word1, word2]|(2,[0,1],[1.0,1.0])|      1.0|      1.0|
+---+--------------+-------------------+---------+---------+
```

Now, for performance reasons, you might want to convert your base Vector to an array of coordinates (or a DenseVector). Feel free to do that. I feel like a `DenseVector` or an `Array` will probably be very close performance-wise, so I would write it this way :

```
// A function to densify the feature vector
val toDense = udf((v:Vector) => v.toDense)
// Replase testDF's feature column with its dense equivalent
val denseDF = testDF.withColumn("feature", toDense($"feature"))
// Work on denseDF as we did on testDF 
denseDF.select((col("*") +: featureCols):_*).show
```

Comment: That is a fantastic answer - it really clarifies the syntax. Now, I can follow your example using the sample DF and it appears it works. But when I use my DF, even when I run your  very first UDF, I get error: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Row` - the same type of error I've been getting all along.

Comment: I've been getting the same error when trying lots of different methods - it's driving me 'round the bend as I don't understand how to deal with it!

Comment: Could you print your dataframe's schema object (eg. `testDF.schema("features")`), and add it to your question for future reference ? I suspect that are different types of Vector object lying around, seeing you are using a Cassandra connector as well.

Comment: The schema is a plain `|-- features: vector (nullable = true)`

Comment: And the `df.schema("features")` output of my DF is `StructField(feature,org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7,true)`- which is EXACTLY the same as the as the output from the testDF. This makes it all the stranger that this code works on one and not the other.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I need to do something similar except explode the SparseVector (generated from IDF transformation) into tuples of (index, idf_value) which can then be processed by ALS. Hopefully you've given me enough to pull it off!

Comment: @EvanZamir I’m really not sure it « means » anything valid to feed the output of IDF to an ALS algorithm. Nonetheless I suggest you ask your own question with a sample input and output to have a better grasp of what you need. (I guess you need a tuple of (index, valueAtIndex) but I’m not even sure).